# How do I add an additional “Cancel account” operation link?

Tags: views, 8, users

On Drupal 8, I'm trying to modify /admin/people to have the cancel button appears under Edit link in operations.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by rewriting operation links field in views:

```
<a href="/user/{{ uid }}/edit">edit</a>
<a href="/user/{{ uid }}/cancel">cancel</a>
```